# D-Optimality for regression of polynomial models in one variable with missing terms

Tags: r, experiment-design, nonlinear-regression, polynomial, optimal

Let's say I have a model that looks as follows:

$$y = x + ax^3 + bx^5 + cx^7 + dx^9$$

Given $n$ free choices for x as input measurements how can I determine which $x$'s I should input to best determine $a,b,c,d$ coefficients. The range for $x$ is $(0,t)$.

Comment: The X range can always be normalized by tea so it should be from 0 to 1.

Answer (score 0):

In your polynomial model there is no coefficient for the linear term and no intercept (and no error term ...) I will assume that is an oversight. The classic book [Optimal Design of Experiments](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0898716047) by  [Frederick Pukelsheim](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedrich_Pukelsheim) analyzes D-optimal designs for polynomial regression, but for models including all polynomial terms up to $d$ ($x^d$). Let us see how this works for your model.

We will use, as in that book, $x$ normalized to the range $[-1, 1]$. As D-optimality is invariant under linear transformations of the predictors, you can just transform the results back to your range. Then, there is the approximate result (for large $d$) that the support points for a D-optimal design can be got from the arcsine distribution:
$$ x_i = \cos\left(\frac{d-i}{d}\pi\right), \quad i=0,1,\dotsc,d
$$
Let us use the package `AlgDesign` in R to check this:

```r
library(AlgDesign)  
d <- 9
A <- data.frame(x=cos(pi*(d-0:d)/d))  
a.des <- optFederov(~ 1 + x + I(x^3) + I(x^5) + I(x^7) + I(x^9), A,
                    approximate=TRUE, evaluateI=TRUE)

a.des
$D
[1] 0.006375102

$A
[1] 115076.8

$I
[1] 6

$Ge
[1] 1

$Dea
[1] 1

$design
   Proportion          x
1         0.1 -1.0000000
2         0.1 -0.9396926
3         0.1 -0.7660444
4         0.1 -0.5000000
5         0.1 -0.1736482
6         0.1  0.1736482
7         0.1  0.5000000
8         0.1  0.7660444
9         0.1  0.9396926
10        0.1  1.0000000
```

So this gives design proportions which are actually all equal, so can be actually realized in an exact design with $N=10$ (or some multiple). You can yourself try this, but replace `A` with a linearly spaced set, and results will not be so nice.

Let us then try to find an exact design with this support points and $N=20$:

```r
e.des <- optFederov(~ 1 + x + I(x^3) + I(x^5) + I(x^7) + I(x^9), rbind(A, A),
                    approximate=FALSE, evaluateI=TRUE, nTrials=20) 

e.des
$D
[1] 0.006375102

$A
[1] 115074.4

$I
[1] 6

$Ge
[1] 1

$Dea
[1] 1

$design
.
.
.
```

(the design just consists of the support points replicated twice). Note that `Ge`, the efficiency compared to the approximate theory design, is 1.

Comment: I lost you at the outset, because this model is *not* invariant under translation, which introduces even powers of $x.$

Comment: @whuber: OK, you mean the model as stated, without intercept, and with the $x$ term as an offset?  Will look into that

Comment: I mean the model with only odd powers of $x.$  The problem with translation persists whether or not an intercept is included.  BTW, your model differs in two more important ways from the one in the question: in addition to including an intercept, it also has a coefficient for $x.$  As written, the question's model is $y-x=ax^3+bx^5+cx^7+dx^9+\varepsilon$ with just four parameters, not six, to be estimated.

Comment: Numerical experiments in finding solutions for up to $n=40$ suggest the arcsine approximation is still pretty good once $n \approx 20$ or so.  This comes within a factor of $2$ of the optimal determinant.  The heteroscedastic model $(y-x)/x^3 = a+b(x^2)+c(x^2)^2+d(x^2)^3+\varepsilon/x^3$ suggests using the square root of the arcsine points and, indeed, this works noticeably better.